# Tree Data with Context menu

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to use the `context menu` within the `tree data` view. But I want to for each stage a different `context menu`. With stage I mean the hierarchy level. I can't offering any code, because I have no approach if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs -

> You can customise the context menu by providing a
>   getContextMenuItems() callback. Each time the context menu is to be
>   shown, the callback is called to retrieve the items to include in the
>   menu. This allows the client application to display a menu
>   individually customised to each cell.

You could implement something like this -

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    getContextMenuItems: getContextMenuItems
};

function getContextMenuItems(params) {

var result;

switch(params.node.level) {
case 0 :
    result = [
        {
            // custom item
            name: 'Alert ' + params.value,
            action: function() {
                window.alert('Alerting about ' + params.value);
            }
        }];
    break;  

case 1 :
    result = ["copy"];
    break;

case 2 :
    result = ["expandAll"];
    break;

case 3 :
    result = ["export"];
    break;

    default:
      result = ["copy","paste, "toolPanel"];
}
return result;
}
```

More details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#built-in-menu-items)